Error in stacking with spatial resampling: response is not a factor at two levels but ‘family = Binomial()
I've coded a graph that performs stacking using the mlr3 package. In the first step, I tuned the parameters of the level 0 learners, and in the final step, I used the predictions from the tuned level 0 learners to obtain the predictions of an ensemble learner. However, when I ran my code, I received this error message:
Error in family@check_y(y) : 
  response is not a factor at two levels but ‘family = Binomial()’
This happened PipeOp classif.glmboost's $train()

Here is a reproducible example:
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:1742, x = runif(1742, -130.88, -61.12), y = runif(1742, 12.12, 61.38), year = runif(1742, 2005, 2020), presence = rep(0:1, each=871), V1 = runif(1742, -3.66247, 2.95120), V2 = runif(1742, -1.6501, 7.5510))
data$presence <- as.factor(data$presence)
## summary(data)
task <- mlr3spatial::as_task_classif_st(x = data, target = "presence", positive = "1", coordinate_names = c("x", "y"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
task$set_col_roles("ID", roles = "space")
task$set_col_roles("year", roles = "time")

learner_avg <- mlr3pipelines::LearnerClassifAvg$new(id = "classif.avg")
learner_avg$predict_type  <- "prob"
learner_avg$param_set$values$measure <- "classif.auc"

source("H:/PipeOpLearnerCV_mod.R")
learner_glmboost <- mlr3::lrn("classif.glmboost", predict_type = "prob", family = "Binomial", mstop = list(mstop = paradox::to_tune(1, 500))$mstop)
learner_gamboost <- mlr3::lrn("classif.gamboost", predict_type = "prob", family = "Binomial", mstop = list(mstop = paradox::to_tune(1, 500))$mstop)
po_learner_glmboost <- PipeOpLearnerCV_mod$new(learner = learner_glmboost, param_vals = list(resampling.method = "sptcv_cstf", resampling.folds = 2))
po_learner_gamboost <- PipeOpLearnerCV_mod$new(learner = learner_gamboost, param_vals = list(resampling.method = "sptcv_cstf", resampling.folds = 2))
level_0_graph = gunion(list(po_learner_glmboost, po_learner_gamboost)) %>>% po("featureunion")
level_0_and_1_graph = level_0_graph %>>% learner_avg
level_0_and_1_graph_learner <- mlr3::as_learner(level_0_and_1_graph)

tuning_instance <- mlr3tuning::auto_tuner(tuner = mlr3tuning::tnr("mbo"), 
                                                 learner =  level_0_and_1_graph_learner,
                                                 resampling = mlr3::rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 2, stratify = TRUE),
                                                 measure = mlr3::msr("classif.auc"),
                                                 terminator =  mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 5, k = 0))

run_resampling <- mlr3::resample(task = task, learner = tuning_instance, resampling = mlr3::rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 2, stratify = TRUE), store_models = TRUE)

Here is my function PipeOpLearnerCV_mod. It is the mlr3pipelines::PipeOpLearnerCV() function that I have modified to integrate a spatial resampling.
PipeOpLearnerCV_mod = R6Class("PipeOpLearnerCV_mod",
                          inherit = PipeOpTaskPreproc,
                          public = list(
                            initialize = function(learner, id = NULL, param_vals = list()) {
                              private$.learner = as_learner(learner, clone = TRUE)
                              if (mlr3pipelines:::paradox_info$is_old) {
                                private$.learner$param_set$set_id = ""
                              }
                              ########################################################################
                              ## My edits
                              id = private$.learner$id
                              ## id = id %??% private$.learner$id
                              # FIXME: can be changed when mlr-org/mlr3#470 has an answer
                              ########################################
                              type = private$.learner$task_type
                              task_type = mlr_reflections$task_types[type, mult = "first"]$task
                              
                              ########################################################################
                              ## My edits
                              private$.crossval_param_set = ps(
                                method = p_fct(levels = c("cv", "insample", "sptcv_cstf", "repeated_sptcv_cstf"), tags = c("train", "required")),
                                folds = p_int(lower = 2L, upper = Inf, tags = c("train", "required")), 
                                repeats = p_int(lower = 1L, upper = Inf),
                                keep_response = p_lgl(tags = c("train", "required"))
                              )
                              ########################################
                              private$.crossval_param_set$values = list(method = "cv", folds = 3, keep_response = FALSE)
                              if (mlr3pipelines:::paradox_info$is_old) {
                                private$.crossval_param_set$set_id = "resampling"
                              }
                              # Dependencies in paradox have been broken from the start and this is known since at least a year:
                              # https://github.com/mlr-org/paradox/issues/216
                              # The following would make it _impossible_ to set "method" to "insample", because then "folds"
                              # is both _required_ (required tag above) and at the same time must be unset (because of this
                              # dependency). We will opt for the least annoying behaviour here and just not use dependencies
                              # in PipeOp ParamSets.
                              # private$.crossval_param_set$add_dep("folds", "method", CondEqual$new("cv"))  # don't do this.
                              
                              super$initialize(id, alist(resampling = private$.crossval_param_set, private$.learner$param_set), param_vals = param_vals, can_subset_cols = TRUE, task_type = task_type, tags = c("learner", "ensemble"))
                            }
                            
                          ),
                          active = list(
                            learner = function(val) {
                              if (!missing(val)) {
                                if (!identical(val, private$.learner)) {
                                  stop("$learner is read-only.")
                                }
                              }
                              private$.learner
                            },
                            learner_model = function(val) {
                              if (!missing(val)) {
                                if (!identical(val, private$.learner)) {
                                  stop("$learner_model is read-only.")
                                }
                              }
                              if (is.null(self$state) || is_noop(self$state)) {
                                private$.learner
                              } else {
                                multiplicity_recurse(self$state, clone_with_state, learner = private$.learner)
                              }
                            },
                            predict_type = function(val) {
                              if (!missing(val)) {
                                assert_subset(val, names(mlr_reflections$learner_predict_types[[private$.learner$task_type]]))
                                private$.learner$predict_type = val
                              }
                              private$.learner$predict_type
                            }
                          ),
                          private = list(
                            .train_task = function(task) {
                              on.exit({private$.learner$state = NULL})
                              
                              # Train a learner for predicting
                              self$state = private$.learner$train(task)$state
                              pv = private$.crossval_param_set$values

                              # Compute CV Predictions
                              if (pv$method != "insample") {
                                rdesc = mlr_resamplings$get(pv$method)
                                if (pv$method == "cv") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds)
                                ########################################################################
                                ## My edits
                                if (pv$method == "sptcv_cstf") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, stratify = TRUE)
                                if (pv$method == "repeated_sptcv_cstf") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, repeats = pv$repeats, stratify = TRUE)
                                ########################################################################
                                rr = resample(task, private$.learner, rdesc)
                                prds = as.data.table(rr$prediction(predict_sets = "test"))
                              } else {
                                prds = as.data.table(private$.learner$predict(task))
                              }
                              
                              private$pred_to_task(prds, task)
                            },
                            
                            .predict_task = function(task) {
                              on.exit({private$.learner$state = NULL})
                              private$.learner$state = self$state
                              prediction = as.data.table(private$.learner$predict(task))
                              private$pred_to_task(prediction, task)
                            },
                            
                            pred_to_task = function(prds, task) {
                              if (!is.null(prds$truth)) prds[, truth := NULL]
                              if (!self$param_set$values$resampling.keep_response && self$learner$predict_type == "prob") {
                                prds[, response := NULL]
                              }
                              renaming = setdiff(colnames(prds), c("row_id", "row_ids"))
                              data.table::setnames(prds, renaming, sprintf("%s.%s", self$id, renaming))
                              
                              # This can be simplified for mlr3 >= 0.11.0;
                              # will be always "row_ids"
                              row_id_col = intersect(colnames(prds), c("row_id", "row_ids"))
                              data.table::setnames(prds, old = row_id_col, new = task$backend$primary_key)
                              task$select(character(0))$cbind(prds)
                            },
                            .crossval_param_set = NULL,
                            .learner = NULL,
                            .additional_phash_input = function() private$.learner$phash
                          )
)

mlr_pipeops$add("learner_cv", PipeOpLearnerCV_mod, list(R6Class("Learner", public = list(id = "learner_cv", task_type = "classif", param_set = ps()))$new()))


I checked the tasks right before it is passed to mboost::glmboost. The target only contains 0. So this cannot work. I think you have to adjust the spatial resampling so that 0 and 1 are in the target.
task$data()$presence

  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 1 0


@bemarc Thank you for your answer. I don't understand why there are no "1"s even though the original data contains 1s. Would a solution be to stratify the target column "presence" even if the data is balanced (an equal number of 1s and 0s)? If not, how can we adjust the spatial resampling? Thank you for your help

Yes your complete region contains 1 and 0 but it seems that the zeros are located in one area. You can set stratify = TRUE for sptcv_cstf.

@bemarc Thank you for your comment. I have modified this line of code if (pv$method == "sptcv_cstf") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, stratify = TRUE) in my PipeOpLearnerCV_mod function above. I also included mlr3::rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 2, stratify = TRUE) in mlr3tuning::auto_tuner and mlr3::resample. However, it doesn't seem to be working. I still get the same error message. Also, I'm wondering if my edits in the PipeOpLearnerCV_mod function are correct (see sections "My edits" in the code)? Thank you for your help.

Did you try to visualize the the folds with https://mlr3spatiotempcv.mlr-org.com/reference/index.html#visualization-of-spatiotemporal-partitions? Maybe you can find the error like this.

You call stratify = FALSE in your "My edits".

@bemarc Thank you for your comment. No, I didn't visualize the folds. But I tested this: rcv = rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 5, stratify = FALSE); rcv$instantiate(task); for(i in 1:5){test <- prop.table(table(task$data(rows = rcv$train_set(i), cols = "presence"))); print(test)} and there was no problem. Yes, in my post, I called stratify = FALSE. But I tested with stratify = TRUE afterwards and it still doesn't work. I keep getting the error message

@bemarc I tested with 20 folds and stratify = FALSE, and I no longer have any 1s. I tested with 20 folds and stratify = TRUE, and I have 1s, but the balance between 0 and 1 (i.e., 0.5 and 0.5) is not maintained. I don't need that many folds, and with 5 folds and 10 folds, I don't get error messages, but there is an imbalance between 0 and 1 with folds = 10 and stratify = TRUE. So, I'm wondering if there's an issue with stratify = TRUE because there is an imbalance for 10 and 20 folds.

Maybe the issue comes from the PipeOpLearnerCV_mod function. Do my edits in the PipeOpLearnerCV_mod function seem correct to you?

There is probably nothing wrong with your code. Are you sure that Spatiotemporal "leave-location-and-time-out" resampling works with your data? The "space" role identifies spatial units but your ID column is unique for each observation. The same is true for the year.

@bemarc Thank you very much. I also thought it could be due to the spatial units (for the temporal units, I thought it was correct since I have multiple observations for the same year). I tested by using the province as the spatial unit, where I have multiple observations per province. But, I get the same error message after a while. I thought LLTO resampling was interesting because I use machine learning models to make both spatial and temporal projections until 2100. I would have liked to provide my dataset in my post, but data repositories like WeTransfer are not allowed.

@bemarc could PipeOpClassBalancing and PipeOpSmote be solutions to explore, even if initially I do not have an imbalanced target feature?
